# Sql server stored procedure with parameter return's all records when no parameter passing to function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have SQL server  stored procedure i want it returns all records when no parameter pass to it , i test the procedure it is return all records when i remove the min and max parameter built it then execute it .

```
alter PROCEDURE SearchBYProjects
@location NVARCHAR(50),
@purpose NVARCHAR(50),
@type NVARCHAR(50),
@min NVARCHAR(50),
@max NVARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT 
    p.ID,
    p.ProjectName, 
    p.Areas, 
    p.PaymentSystem, 
    p.ReceivedDate,    
    p.PropertyClassification, 
    p.ProjectImage,         
    l.LocationName,
    Pur.PurposeName,            
    t.TypeName
 FROM dbo.Projects AS p 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Purpose pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.[Types] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
 WHERE UPPER(ISNULL(l.LocationName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@location) + '%'
 AND UPPER(ISNULL(pur.PurposeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@purpose) + '%'
 AND UPPER(ISNULL(t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@type) + '%'
 AND  UPPER(ISNULL(p.Areas,'')) BETWEEN @min AND @max
 GO

 EXEC dbo.SearchBYProjects @location ='',@purpose='',@type='',@min='',@max=''
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add only:

```
or coalesce(@location,@purpose,@type,@min,@max) is null
```

Try to not use functions on arguments you search. When you use function for (ISNULL, COALESCE, UPPER, udf..) your argument isn't SARG anymore. Don't use like with '%dasda' if it is not necasary - use fulltext search on names, location, purpose (or unstructured data).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
alter PROCEDURE SearchBYProjects
    @location NVARCHAR(50) = null,
    @purpose NVARCHAR(50) = null,
    @type NVARCHAR(50) = null,
    @min NVARCHAR(50) = null,
    @max NVARCHAR(50) = null
AS
SELECT 
    p.ID,
    p.ProjectName, 
    p.Areas, 
    p.PaymentSystem, 
    p.ReceivedDate,    
    p.PropertyClassification, 
    p.ProjectImage,         
    l.LocationName,
    Pur.PurposeName,            
    t.TypeName
 FROM dbo.Projects AS p 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Purpose pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.[Types] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
 WHERE (@location is null or UPPER(ISNULL(l.LocationName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@location) + '%')
 AND (@purpose is null or UPPER(ISNULL(pur.PurposeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@purpose) + '%')
 AND (@type is null or UPPER(ISNULL(t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@type) + '%')
 AND (@min is null or UPPER(ISNULL(p.Areas,'')) >= @min)
 AND (@max is null or UPPER(ISNULL(p.Areas,'')) <= @max)
 GO

 EXEC dbo.SearchBYProjects
```

Note that this way will also let you pass some nulls and not others e.g.

```
EXEC dbo.SearchBYProjects @type='SomeType'
```

will return everything with type = 'SomeType'

Worth mentioning that if "Areas" is a string this might not act as expected e.g. '110' comes before '2', and between '10' and '20'. So if these are numbers then you might want to convert them in the where clause.

Comment: i want execute the procedure with no parameters and return's all records this you write it must pass parameter to return all records ?,i changed the Area column data type from nvarchar to int datatype also not working like i want to return all records if i do not pass parameters ?

Comment: this line i want to execute   EXEC dbo.SearchBYProjects @location ='',@purpose='',@type='',@min='',@max=''

Comment: This will work but has some potentially serious performance impact. Take a peek at this article for how you can improve this type of catch all query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Given that OP wants to return all records, I assume its not a huge amount of data so performance should be just fine. hashim you could replace "is null" with "= '' " everywhere in my code if you want it to work with params like that. Or add "or @location = '' " etc to each part of the where clause

Answer (score 1):

Ditto everything that Sean and Deadsheep39 said. To expand on what deadsheep39 said, your WHERE clause could look like this:

```
WHERE 
( 
      UPPER(ISNULL(l.LocationName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@location) + '%'
  AND UPPER(ISNULL(pur.PurposeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@purpose) + '%'
  AND UPPER(ISNULL(t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' + UPPER(@type) + '%'
  AND UPPER(ISNULL(p.Areas,'')) BETWEEN @min AND @max
)
OR COALESCE(@location,@purpose,@type,@min,@max) IS NULL;
```

If you go this route make sure to look at the article Sean posted.

Because you're doing this in a stored proc you could also handle this requirement like this in your proc (this is how I'd do it):

```
IF COALESCE(@location,@purpose,@type,@min,@max) IS NULL
  SELECT 
     p.ID,
     p.ProjectName, 
     p.Areas, 
     p.PaymentSystem, 
     p.ReceivedDate,    
     p.PropertyClassification, 
     p.ProjectImage,         
     l.LocationName,
     Pur.PurposeName,            
     t.TypeName
  FROM dbo.Projects AS p 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Purpose pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.[Types] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
ELSE
  SELECT 
     p.ID,
     p.ProjectName, 
     p.Areas, 
     p.PaymentSystem, 
     p.ReceivedDate,    
     p.PropertyClassification, 
     p.ProjectImage,         
     l.LocationName,
     Pur.PurposeName,            
     t.TypeName
  FROM dbo.Projects AS p 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS l ON p.LocationID = l.ID      
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Purpose pur ON p.PurposeID = pur.ID 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.[Types] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.ID
  WHERE l.LocationName LIKE N'%' + @location + '%'
  AND pur.PurposeName LIKE N'%' + @purpose + '%'
  AND t.TypeName,N'')) LIKE N'%' @type + '%'
  AND  p.Areas BETWEEN @min AND @max;
```

Then, when executing the proc you would always want to do a recompile. E.g.:

```
EXECUTE <your proc> WITH RECOMPILE;
```